# How do I hide all windows, past and future, of an App in macOS?

Tags: mac, macos, automator

I have a script that is continually opening a new window of an App and then that window closes and the process repeats. However, even if I click Hide on the App, it only hides the window open at that time and all future windows still pop up in front of everything else that I'm doing.

If I assign the App to another Desktop, it switches to that Desktop every time a new window from the App opens. I basically can't do anything else on the computer while the script is running.

For reference, the App is being opened through an Automator Folder Action, so perhaps there is something I can set there. The app is [ABBYY FineReader](https://www.abbyy.com/finereader/).

Comment: The window behavior you've described is the default and to my knowledge there are no settings in the FineReader Preferences and or System Preferences to _always hide_ all application windows. You'll have to try adding the appropriate AppleScript code to the Folder Action that will do the following (if possible). Keep the target App and its window in the background and or set the window to be minimized or not visible. Without knowing how your Folder Action is presently coded and what it's doing, I'm not going to waste time suggesting any specific code at this time.